# Anti-freeze to use on an old classic truck 1953 International

Tags: coolant, cooling-system, truck, classic

What type of anti-freeze should I use on my 1953 international pickup truck with a stock radiator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular ethylene glycol was the antifreeze used then as now. The corrosion inhibitors , and other additives have changed and vary from brand to brand , but basically the same stuff. In '53 there were a few still using methanol/alcohol , but it was a high risk of fire. Modern corrosion inhibitors focus on aluminum but should work on your copper and brass radiator and cast iron engine.

Answer (score 1):

Ethylene Glycol ... you know ... the green stuff? Prestone. Peak. Walmart brand. Generic from Princess Auto. It will all work just fine.

Comment: Some use orange dye ,so you know it is new.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - I'd assume it's orange so it will confuse you with other OAT type antifreeze like DEXCOOL.

Comment: My bad, maybe there is something new . But after reading several sites ,I don't know what the generic is for OAT. There is a lot of talk of corrosion inhibiters and not the basic material. Amine ,nitrite ,phosphate, and silicate are all corrosion inhibitor types  -which are not in OAT but they won't say what is in OAT.

Comment: @blacksmith37 OAT is "organic acid technology" compared with IAT (inorganic) for older formulations. OAT has longer life because takes longer to become too acidic, but otherwise has lower corrosion protection. Modern engine designs specify it for its long life. IAT should really be replaced every 30k miles.

Comment: 'Organic acid technology" does not define anything